# Actualizar un div con ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax

¡Hola! Tengo este código, si, cometo muchos errores en el código, soy nuevo usando **AJAX** y **Javascript**.

```
var turno_actual = 0;

function desplegarAlerta() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $('#turno').load('./ajax/sisben.php');
    }, 1000 );
  })

function refrescaTurno() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "prueba1.php",
    dataType:'json'
  }).done(function(response) {
    if(response.turno != turno_actual) {
      turno_actual = response.turno;
      desplegarAlerta();
    }
    window.setTimeout(refrescaTurno, 2000);
  });
}

refrescaTurno();
```

Pues la idea es que se actualice el `div` cada vez que haya un cambio en la `db`, pero pude hacer una alerta usando `swal` y funciona.

foto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
var turno_actual = 0;
function desplegarAlerta() {
  swal({
    title: "siguiente turno : " + turno_actual,
    text: "Se envio correctamente",
    icon: "success",
    button: true
  });
}


function refrescaTurno() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "prueba1.php",
    dataType:'json'
  }).done(function(response) {
    if(response.turno != turno_actual) {
      turno_actual = response.turno;
      desplegarAlerta();
    }
    window.setTimeout(refrescaTurno, 2000);
  });
}

refrescaTurno();
```

Pero al intentar hacerlo con solo el `div` que esta en la página, 
con el código que deje arriba no me muestra el número.

El código que estoy usando para que me funcione por el momento es este:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var refreshId =  setInterval(function() {
    $('#turno-sisben').load('./vistas/ajax/sisben.php');
    $('#turno-familia').load('./vistas/ajax/familias_en_accion.php');
    $('#turno-salud').load('./vistas/ajax/salud.php');
    $('#turno-despacho').load('./vistas/ajax/despacho.php');
    $('#turno-adulto').load('./vistas/ajax/adulto_mayor.php');
  }, 1000 );
})
```

pero se sobre carga cuando se usan muchas peticiones al mismo tiempo ya que cada segundo se actualiza

Comment: Si lo que quieres es una comunicación cliente<->servidor deberías usar websockets. Si lo quieres hacer con Ajax debes colocar un intervalo de una función que verifique si hay novedades cada cierto tiempo

Comment: como tal yo estoy usando esto que lo colocare en la ultima parte pero al hacerlo sobrecargo el servidor y explota sale  cuando se sobre carga

Comment: mi recomendacion es que aprendas sobre websockets ya que los setinterval consumen demasiado recurso y saturan el serber

Comment: Ok Gracias investigare al respecto y me podrías mostrar un ejemplo para ir guiándome se ria de mucha ayuda

Comment: Pues como no quieres que se sobrecargue si lo haces cada segundo y no le das tiempo de cargar por completo la primer petición solo dale mas tiempo actualiza cada minuto o así por el estilo.

Comment: a hora mismo le coloque que se actualice cada 5 segundo pero según lo que yo quiero hacer es que se actualice solo cuando halla un cambio en la base de datos

Comment: Yo tengo un problema con un WebSocket, quizas alguno de los presentes estan bien ilustrados en el tema, del cual me puedan iluminar con este error ? @AndySamuel y andy gibbs ?

Comment: @memezhukulento websockets matiene una comunicacion bidireccional entre cliente servidor en vez de tu pedirle informacion al servidor los websockets te mandan informacion sin que se la pidas si hay algun cambio en la base de datos es una de  las tecnologia mas usada o la mas usada por los grandes desarrolladores en cuanto a rendimiento se trata actualmente mi projecto corre con websockets y diria que es lo mejor que  puede existir

Comment: @srJJ dime que quieres saver sobre websockets

Comment: @andygibbs me podrías mostrar un ejemplo que se parezca a lo que intento hacer con lo del websockets

Comment: Lo que sucede es que si lo pongo a funcionar me ejecuta la funcion, pero en el cliente, cuando asigno algo muestro una alertar informando del nuevo evento asignado, y desde donde lo envio deseo mandar una alerta de que fue satisfactorio, (aqui es el problema) que recarga a pagina y no me deja mostrar la alerta, y no entiendo el por que de ellos

Comment: @memezhukulento aqui fue donde yo empese a llenarme de conocimientos sobre sockets puedes buscar la documentacion en español tambien, es facil de aplicar con poca practica y entendimiento https://socket.io/get-started/chat

Answer (score 4):

Hay una forma de hacerlo, además de `setinterval`+`ajax` o wesockets que es usando [server-sent event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) (la documentación en español está incompleta), la idea es similar a los websockets pero solo de servidor a cliente, no bidireccional. Te dejo un ejemplo sacado de [acá](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp), pero modificando el servidor para repetir una operación:

Cliente:

```
var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
    //hacer algo con el mensaje del servidor, que esta en event.data.
};
```

Servidor:

```
    <?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

do {
//SELECT * FROM .....
//Y el echo de la query aca. 

  sleep(5);
  //usamos el while para mantener la conexión
} while(true);

?>
```

Comment: Disculpa, y cuando los datos son desde la BD, seria como estas haciendo peticiones constantes ?

Comment: quede en las mismas xD

Comment: es que no quiero someter a la base de datos a constantes ataques de informacion ya que la puedo saturar, entonces debo saber bien, como ya dije implemente un socket pero tiene un defecto que me recarga la pagina de envio y no me muestra la alerta

Comment: la cuestion es que son muchos usuario a la ves que estarian haciendo la misma consulta, por eso lo mas simple es socket, pero me ha generado un error que no he podido encontrar. de otro modo el programa dejaria de ser escalable y eficiente

Comment: @srJJ pero en el código que mandás estás haciendo ajax.

Comment: si, es ajax....

Comment: ajax no es socket